# Forcing list to flow around div element in responsive page layout using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive site and the blue boxes below are "News" items. The white box is a teaser-kind-of box with different styling.

(These boxes are just a cut out of a bigger floated box-flow with lots of different types of boxes.)

The problem is to be able to flow the news-items around the teaser box on desktop mode and then separating/tiling them in the mobile layout.

Markup-wise the news list is contained in a div with 4 divs inside. I think this is the big problem. Putting another div in the same level as the news items wouldn't be a problem. I am seeking any ideas or tips about any super-frameworks.

[image]

Please feel free to mess up this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4Pr9/

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="box-layout">
    <div class="box list-container">
        <div class="box news-box">This is a news item</div>
        <div class="box news-box">This is a news item</div>
        <div class="box news-box">This is a news item</div>
        <div class="box news-box">This is a news item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box teaser-box">This is the teaser box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
 width: 400px;   
}
.box-layout{
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
.box{
    float: left;
}
.list-container{
    background: #509EB8;

}
.news-box{
    width: 100%;
    background: #003057;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 60px;
}

.teaser-box{
    background: #B03C3F;
    height: 135px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this happen without having to break the div containing the news-items. I'm not sure how dynamic this solution is though but it might give some viewers good ideas to solve similar issues.

By putting the teaser div before the list in the markup and then floating it to the right, the text will "stop" at the edge of the teaser. However, the background of the news-item-box still floated below the teaser.

I removed the background, nested another text element with the same styling as the news-item and added a a spacer that pushed the text element to the right making the illusion that the news item actually "stopped" before the teaser...

[image]

It's a bit hard to explain but please have a look on the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mALKb/

**Markup**

```
<div class="box-layout">
    <!-- Teaser box OUTSIDE the list container below -->
    <div class="box teaser-box">This is the teaser box</div>

    <!-- List container for the news items -->
    <div class="list-container">
        <!-- Full width boxes -->
        <div class="box news-box-featured">This is a news item</div>
        <div class="box news-box-featured">This is a news item</div> 

        <!-- None full width news items -->
        <div class="box news-box">
            <div class="spacer">&nbsp;&nbsp;spacer</div>
            <div class="text">This is a news item</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box news-box">
            <div class="spacer">&nbsp;&nbsp;spacer</div>
            <div class="text">This is a news item.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana;
}
.news-box-featured{
    width: 100%;
    background: #003057;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.teaser-box {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    background: #B03C3F;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.list-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.news-box{
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.text{
    background: #003057;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
}
.spacer{
    border: dashed 1px #666666;
    height: 58px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 208px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In this way I don't have to use a framework. I could also easily style this to be a long list of blocks for devices with smaller screens...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could benefit from using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It's a responsive design framework that handles exactly the kind of thing you're referring to.

It uses a row/column approach for responsive design that would handle your scenario easily.